# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem. The problem happened when I deploy this project to production server using Apache web server. I try to change DocumentRoot on Apache webservers. ([CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server)) but still no luck.

But if I run the project under development server using ./cake server command (http://localhost:8765/) it seems ok. I can create, retrieve, update, delete. No database error

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message - which comes from the database?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue is also related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360462/cakephp-sqlstatehy00014-error) about cakePhp 3.x

The error comes from the DebugKit plugin, which is activated in your site, as it's obvious by the screenshot.
You need to make the file ROOT/tmp/debug_kit.sqlite, writable.